# best way to export a table in multiple small files

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What is the best way to export a large table (in Oracle, 246 million rows) into small csv flat files. Is there an automated way I can do that or do I have to spool small chunks of data manually?

Thanks!

Comment: You really want CSV, not a true (datapump) export, which can be split into small files automatically with the [`FILESIZE` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16536/dp_export.htm#sthref86)?

Comment: no, don't necessarily need csv, just a way to get the data into small chunks...